# Crashed whilst crashing with this exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown constant type 18

Tags: java, aspectj

I am trying to build a mvn project, though it works properly in local (Java version 1.8.0_102), but the build is failing in one of the job required for CI (Java version tried are: 1.8.0_102, 1.8.0_172, 1.8.0_144. Exception coming is:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Crashed whilst crashing with this exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown constant type 18
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.weave(BcelWeaver.java:1721)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.weaveWithoutDump(BcelWeaver.java:1644)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.weaveAndNotify(BcelWeaver.java:1409)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.weave(BcelWeaver.java:1191)
    at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.compiler.AjPipeliningCompilerAdapter.weaveQueuedEntries(AjPipeliningCompilerAdapter.java:514)
    at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.compiler.AjPipeliningCompilerAdapter.queueForWeaving(AjPipeliningCompilerAdapter.java:447)
    at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.compiler.AjPipeliningCompilerAdapter.afterProcessing(AjPipeliningCompilerAdapter.java:432)
    at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.compiler.CompilerAdapter.ajc$after$org_aspectj_ajdt_internal_compiler_CompilerAdapter$5$6b855184(CompilerAdapter.aj:103)
    at org.aspectj.org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.process(Compiler.java:909)
    at org.aspectj.org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.processCompiledUnits(Compiler.java:550)
    at org.aspectj.org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:462)
    at org.aspectj.org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:417)
    at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.core.builder.AjBuildManager.performCompilation(AjBuildManager.java:1036)
    at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.core.builder.AjBuildManager.performBuild(AjBuildManager.java:272)
    at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.core.builder.AjBuildManager.batchBuild(AjBuildManager.java:185)
    at org.aspectj.ajdt.ajc.AjdtCommand.doCommand(AjdtCommand.java:114)
    at org.aspectj.ajdt.ajc.AjdtCommand.runCommand(AjdtCommand.java:60)
    at org.aspectj.tools.ajc.Main.run(Main.java:371)
    at org.aspectj.tools.ajc.Main.runMain(Main.java:248)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.aspectj.AbstractAjcCompiler.execute(AbstractAjcCompiler.java:544)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown constant type 18
    at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.classfile.ConstantPool.constantToString(ConstantPool.java:212)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.LazyMethodGen$BodyPrinter.printInstruction(LazyMethodGen.java:780)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.LazyMethodGen$BodyPrinter.print(LazyMethodGen.java:724)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.LazyMethodGen$BodyPrinter.run(LazyMethodGen.java:651)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.LazyMethodGen.print(LazyMethodGen.java:612)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.LazyClassGen.printOne(LazyClassGen.java:860)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.LazyClassGen.print(LazyClassGen.java:819)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.LazyClassGen.toLongString(LazyClassGen.java:807)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.weave(BcelWeaver.java:1719)
```

In the pom.xml file following dependencies are already added:

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>  //version 
    4.3.8.RELEASE
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId> //version 
    4.3.8.RELEASE
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId> //version 1.8.10
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId> //version 1.8.10
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId> //version 1.8.10
        </dependency>
```

I have also tried -XnoInline in  of spring-boot-maven-plugin
Any help will really be appreciated.

Comment: I encountered this problem too.

It worked after removing aspectjweaver dependency 1.8.10

Comment: Have tried this as well, this also doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: It seems to be triggered by using the new Java lambda syntax. have you wrote lambda expression, Also check this code properly, https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=490315